# How to make an uploaded file "clickable" on Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm following this guide https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/ to create a file upload on my project. It's working properly with this code:

```
<input type="file" class="file-input (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileUpload>

<div class="file-upload">
   {{fileName || "No file uploaded yet."}}
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="upload-btn"
      (click)="fileUpload.click()">
        <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

and:

```
onFileSelected(event) {
   const file:File = event.target.files[0];
   if (file) {
      this.fileName = file.name;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("thumbnail", file);
      const upload$ = this.http.post("/api/thumbnail-upload", formData);
      upload$.subscribe();
   }
}
```

This line `{{fileName || "No file uploaded yet."}}` lets me see the name of the file uploaded, but I'd like to have this name "clickable" and open the file I uploaded.  How can I do it?

EDIT: The file uploaded it's either a pdf or an image, and I'd like to open it once clicked.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ```open``` the file you uploaded ? It is a text file you want to show contents of ? Is it an image you want to display on the webpage ?

Comment: It could be a pdf or an image, I'd like to open the file when it's clicked

Comment: Would you like to open it inside your own application or by using a browser like Chrome?

Comment: I'd just like to open it, so on the browser it's perfect as well

Comment: The thing is that input[type="file"] does not store the local path but stores the file in memory. So if you were to show the img or pdf file you would need to read it on memory and display it in your html. You can solve the img part easy but for displaying PDF files you would need a plugin in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below solution

**In HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" class="file-input (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileUpload>

<div class="file-upload">
   {{fileName || "No file uploaded yet."}}
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="upload-btn"
      (click)="openFileUpload(fileUpload)">
        <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

**In TS**

```
openFileUpload(fileUpload){
   document.getElementById("fileUpload").click();
}

onFileSelected(event) {
   const file:File = event.target.files[0];
   if (file) {
      this.fileName = file.name;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("thumbnail", file);
      const upload$ = this.http.post("/api/thumbnail-upload", formData);
      upload$.subscribe();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be better future proof if you explained _what_  you changed and _why_...